# What user demographics are available in iOS?

Tags: ios

`NSLocale preferredLanguages` gives the user's selected language and `UIDevice` gives some other device info like hardware model and OS version.

But are there any other demographics such as gender and birthday available?  Or is that only possible by prompting the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this information is not available from the device, nor can you access the apple id information. You can request the user for this information, plus request the user  user for his contact information on the contacts application database.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would be [Flurry](http://flurry.com). They have demographics which they obtain by supplied information from other applications the user uses. They also have an algorithm to best guess demographics they don't have info for.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, this information is not available from the device. If you want to have an estimation of the use of the app by gender or age, then I recommend you to integrate [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com):

> Flurry Estimates analyzes demographic distributions across all of the applications that use Flurry Analytics, and attempts to determine the demographics of applications where incomplete information is available. Similar to Benchmarking, this process runs in aggregate over anonymized data, so no individual data is used for a given person or application. The accuracy of the estimates varies on a number of factors, including whether users pass you demographic information in your app. The more data you collect and provide to Flurry Analytics the more accurate the estimates will be for all of your users.

Unfortunately, it's not possible to react programmatically depending on demographics.

Answer (score 0):

The best chance of obtaining this would be to ask the user for permission to access the device contacts (ABAddressBook framework) and then ask them to identify themselves from that list (call it 'set up account'). I do this in one of my own apps.

Although the iOS uses heuristics to identify the device user 'me' in the inbuilt Contacts app, it doesn't support obtaining this same information programatically via the framework.

Even then, contacts does not record gender, and it's a long shot the user will have entered their birthday.

Comment: Please don't do that for the purpose of analytics.

Comment: No, it's for autocompletion of some user visible fields - all above board.